# Use "will" or "would" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The following dialogue is part of a TOEIC test I am editing:

W: Good afternoon, sir. What seems to be the problem?
M: Well, all of my joints are aching, and I think I have a fever.
W: Have you registered at the front desk?
M: Yes, I have. And they sent me here.
W: Okay. Please give me your health insurance card and wait outside until your name is called.

The following is a question asked about the dialogue:

What **would** the man likely receive right after being called?

The answer is, "A temperature examination."

I feel that "would" should be changed to "will" as we are asking about a prediction, even if the text isn't about a "real" situation.  I also feel that the word "likely" is used which to me is asking for the prediction use of "will."

My question: Is "would" acceptable?

Comment: I think would is acceptable here because of the past participle at the end.

Comment: I don't like either. I would reword it _What is the man likely to receive right after being called_?

Answer (score 2):

> Will is a definite statement, which means that you use it when you are certain that the future action is going to take place.[1](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-would-and-will/#ixzz4B4QQ0qvO)

Because the question asks what the man is only likely to receive, there is no definite outcome suggested and using the word 'will', would be inappropriate.

Comment: According to that analysis we'd never say "will probably". but we do! "I'll probably get there around 7", for example.

Comment: Good point! I will need to reconsider my habitual speech going forward :)